# How to submit Contact Form 7 programatically

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form

I am trying to submit a contact form 7 with the form id using WPCF7_ContactForm class that the plugin has

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php');

function submit_cf7_form_by_id($form_id, $form_data) {
    // Create an instance of WPCF7_ContactForm class
    $wpcf7_contact_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_instance($form_id);

    // Check if the form instance exists
    if ($wpcf7_contact_form) {
        echo 'form found';
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::create($form_id);

        // Populate form fields with data
        foreach ($form_data as $field_name => $field_value) {
            $submission->set_field($field_name, $field_value);
        }

        $result = $wpcf7_contact_form->submit($submission);

        if ($result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am running this function on wordpress init hook because I am currently testing

```
function cf7_submit_function() {
    
    $form_id = '0aba882';
    $form_data = array(
        'your-name' => 'John Doe',
        'your-email' => 'john@example.com',
    );

    $submission_result = submit_cf7_form_by_id($form_id, $form_data);

    if ($submission_result) {
        echo "CF7 form submitted successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to submit CF7 form.";
    }
}
add_action('init', 'cf7_submit_function');
```

But it is not getting the contact form 7 instance

I want to submit contact form without using default contact form submit functionality, so I can pass form data separately with form id and submit contact form through code

Comment: _"But it is not getting the contact form 7 instance"_ - the `init` hook might simply be too early to do this, many plugins initialize their own functionality via that same hook. Try https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_loaded/ instead.